# React-router-dom, NavLink - problem with rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some problem with NavLinks - it wont render my Header component.

Here is the code

**>> App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../styles/App.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./Header";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
import Page from "./Page";
import Footer from "./Footer";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="app">
          <header>{<Header />}</header>
          <main>
            <aside>{<Navigation />}</aside>
            <section className="page">{<Page />}</section>
          </main>

          <footer>{<Footer />}</footer>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**>> Navigation.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import "../styles/Navigation.css";

const list = [
  { name: "Start", path: "/", exact: true },
  { name: "Produkty", path: "products" },
  { name: "Kontakt", path: "contact" },
  { name: "Panel admina", path: "admin" }
];

const Navigation = () => {
  const menu = list.map((element) => (
    <li key={element.name}>
      <NavLink to={element.path} exact={element.exact ? element.exact : false}>
        {element.name}
      </NavLink>
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <nav className="main">
      <ul>{menu}</ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

**>>Header.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/Header.css";

import img1 from "../images/header1.jpg";
import img2 from "../images/header2.jpg";
import img3 from "../images/header3.jpg";

const Header = () => {
  const images = [img1, img2, img3];
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  console.log(index);
  const img = images[index];

  return (
    <>
      <img src={img} alt="header" />
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

I know i could solve this problem in other ways (like using `Switch` and `Route` in Header.js) but i wonder why it wont render my site when i click my links(NavLinks). It doesnt render Header component again, just in first site loading.

Comment: can you remove the `{}` around your Header in the App.js file ?

Comment: I removed but nothing changes

Comment: Clicking on a NavLink will change the route and will render the component which matches the path in the `Route` component. I don't see you `Route` component in your code .